# how to use "update-alternatives" to manage multiple installed version of the same app

Tags: paths, update-alternatives

I frequently encounter path related problems while compiling  or running an app.I have two versions of **node** in my system, one is from official repo, the other manually installed from source. Today I wanted to compile **brackets**, when I run `npm install` it asked me to use later version such as 1.4.20. Default version of it is in `/usr/bin/npm` which did't work. The manually installed one is in `/usr/local/bin/npm`

Is there any way to make  `/usr/local/bin/npm` as default path using `update-alternatives` or another method?

For example you can set default text editor with

```
    sudo update-alternatives --config editor
```

Comment: Read this extended manpage: http://linux.die.net/man/8/update-alternatives

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've found how to do that. At first I checked out default path of  `npm` which is older version (1.3.10) in `/usr/bin/npm` , I noticed that it's a symbolic link to  `/usr/share/npm/bin/npm-cli.js` I removed it

```
    sudo unlink /usr/bin/npm
```

Then I tried following command

```
   sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/npm  npm /usr/local/bin/npm 10
   sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/npm  npm /usr/share/npm/bin/npm-cli.js 20
```

Now I can easily switch between them using

```
  sudo update-alternatives --config npm
```

It works well

Answer (score 2):

Since you mentioned **node**, I thought I might point out that this is a good opportunity to use the [N installation manager for NodeJS](https://github.com/tj/n).  If I have a "higher level" package manager like this available, I'll typically use it over *update-alternatives*.  It's generally less complicated than trying to track down important files on your own, IMO.  That said, I think *update-alternatives* will still work.

Comment: Another choice is [*nvm – Node Version Manager*](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm).